# composer autoload classmap with psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am trying to change an autoloading system that I've written before.
I'm using composer and at the moment I'm autoloading just one library with class map.

```
"autoload": {
 "classmap": ["libs/"]
}
```

I want to add a psr-4 loader for the rest of the files and to be able to call the files under libs without namespaces and without "use" them' kind of like aliases in laravel. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
"autoload": {
 "classmap": ["libs/"],
 "psr-4": {
  "App\\": ""
 }
}
```

So eventually if in "libs" I have the Session class I'm calling it as:

```
Session::get('anything')
```

but now after trying to add the psr-4 and calling it from within a namespaced class

```
namespace App\models;

Class User{
 function get(){
  return Session::get('anything');
 }
}
```

It won't work anymore because it looks for session within the user's namespace.
I know there are many frameworks which implements it out of the box with aliases.., it's just that this project is kinda old and I'm trying to organize it a bit and get rid of all the requires anywhere - at the moment each model has to be required.

Comment: `\Session::get('anything');` use like this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I want to add a psr-4 loader for the rest of the files and to be able to call the files under libs without namespaces and without "use" them' kind of like aliases in laravel.

You can't use the classes without either adding `use` or adding the fully qualified namespace path starting with the backslash `\`. This has nothing to do with the way you load these classes, but is a basic requirement of PHP itself - so there is no way around it no matter how you'd like to design your autoloading.

As was commented, adding a backslash works, but this is the required minimum:

```
namespace App\models;
Class User{
  function get(){
    return \Session::get('anything');
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, i can see it won't happen due to too many changes.., how does laravel do it? i mean they define an array of aliases that can be called, same as a classmap..

Comment: If you can point me to the documentation of Laravel that explains what you want, I'd be able to understand your task. But I doubt you'll be able to do what you want because even Laravel cannot violate the PHP syntax rules. I think it is more likely that you misunderstood that Laravel feature, but I cannot judge at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up writing another class that aliasing any classses that i want so i will be able to call them out of the box.

you can see it here:

https://github.com/shahafan/SAmvc-App/blob/master/Config/Aliases.php

basically i'm just using the php class_alias function so i can load all the classes that i want before using them.
i think laravel does it the same way.